# Accommodation that accepts foreigners in Dandong, China

Tags: accommodation, regulations, china

Here in my hostel in Beijing there's a European couple who want to travel to [Dandong](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Dandong), which is a city right on the North Korean border.

So Wikivoyage lists some suggested places to stay but, along with all the places in their Lonely Planet, none of the places will accept bookings from foreign guests.

Obviously this is deemed a sensitive area. But also obviously it was recently possible to stay in places listed in the aforementioned travel guides.

Are there some known hotels or other accommodation in Dandong which have permission for foreign guests to stay, or is the whole city now off-limits to tourists who wish to stay overnight?

If it's really not possible to stay in the city right now, the closest place nearby where it is possible to stay would also be of interest.

Comment: Related: ** [In which places in China can travellers not stay at just any random local hotel?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22927)**

Comment: The couple managed finally, after several false starts, to make a booking with a branch of the Chinese hotel chatin "Home Inn". In one of the links in my previous question I recall somebody in some area even being denied accommodation by the same chain in some part of China. The couple are going to email me their experience and I'll then comment or answer.

Comment: Oh well they never emailed me, sorry I can't update ...

Comment: I stayed in Dandong in 2013 in an ordinary hotel, and I am from the EU.

Answer (score 5):

The standard online Chinese travel agents (elong, ctrip) seem to be able to make bookings in Dandong, starting from Y160 (USD 26) or so for two.

I realize you can get cheaper dives in many places, but doesn't that answer the question adequately? The government probably wants a bit better control in a sensitive border area.

Comment: Ah so maybe knowing where to look for booking hotels online in China might be the key. I never noticed those in my two months in China, but then again I was probably staying in the places you consider to dives (-:

Comment: Perhaps. The one I booked through them in Harbin was pretty grim. It came with standard stinky worn carpet and a goldfish bowl containing a dead fish (that didn't get changed during my stay). Big room though.

Comment: Haha doesn't sound much different to the kind of rooms I stayed in then (-:

Comment: The Chinese reviews for cheap hotels are a hoot. "Urine smell". Water didn't work, complained and staff was rude. Etc. etc. ;-)

Comment: Since originally posting this question I have been back on more trips to China. I know now for a fact that ctrip lists many places that foreigners can't stay at. The booking systems are likely all computerized so will let you book but you won't be permitted to stay when you show up. A couple of times I asked a Chinese to call for me and ask if places allowed foreigners. I don't know if ctrip always lists phone numbers though. Many booking systems don't provide means for you to contact the accommodation directly sidestepping the system.

Comment: @hippietrail Thanks for the update. I wonder if ctrip has the info if you call them - they were surprisingly helpful when I had to change a reservation.

Comment: Good point. I hate even using the phone in Spanish, which unlike Chinese, I'm conversant in. Ctrip seemed to list many places no longer operating though unless I'm confusing the ctrip web search results with other web search results. I had a terrible time finding a place both still existing and taking foreigners in both Shenzhen and Xiamen last year.

Comment: @hippietrail I used English.. No problem.

Answer (score 4):

When I visited Dandong in June 2015, I stayed in the [Hanting Express Dandong Train Station hotel](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g303754-d1519714-Reviews-Hanting_Express_Dandong_Train_Station-Dandong_Liaoning.html), which is close to the city center and the river. I am a US citizen.